# Set of object contains by object with value (not reference) (java 7)

Tags: java, set, contains

I have my object with some feilds.

```
public class MyObject{

   private String a;
   private String b;

}
```

I have a Set contains objects like this :

```
Set<MyObject> thirdSet = new HashSet<MyObject>();

Set<MyObject> firstSet=getFirstSet();

Set<MyObject> secondSet = getSecondeSet();


for (MyObjectobj : firstSet) {
  if (!secondSet.contains(obj)) {
    thirdSet.add(obj);
  }
}
```

I need to select all obj that not contains in my secondSet into thridSet (obj with value not by reference)
Is it possible or using collection is more better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `Object#equals` and `Object#hashCode` in MyObject.java.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof MyObject)) {
        return false;
    }

    MyObject m = (MyObject) o;

    return a.equals(m.a) && b.equals(m.b);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(a, b);
}
```

Also if you're allowed to use external libraries, you should check out Guava's `Sets#difference`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to override both equals and hashcode methods in your object. I'd recommend using the java 7 Objects utility methods if you can to prevent NullPointerExceptions.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (!(other instanceof MyObject)) {
        return false;
    }
    MyObject that = (MyObject) other;
    return Objects.equals(a, that.a) && Objects.equals(b, that.b);
}

@Override
public int hashcode() {
    Objects.hash(a, b);
}
```

I'd also recommend taking a look at the third party library Guava if possible which would simplify your code.

```
Set<MyObject> thirdSet = new HashSet<>(Sets.difference(firstSet, secondSet));
```

Note wrapping it in a new HashSet so it can be modified (if you don't need to modify it you can remove that)